# When using asset pipeline, how to stylesheet_link_tag for static CSS assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use the asset-pipeline with `sass-rails`. The problem I'm having is I have some CSS from libraries that I don't want to be compiled with the rest of the stuff.

I tried putting it in `public/stylesheets`, but when I try to include the file in my app I get `Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError`

What do I need to do to get Rails to look at the right place for static CSS files? Or is there some default place where I'm not putting it properly?

Edit: Double-checked and it doesn't work for JavaScripts either. Reading http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/jquery-ui-css-and-images-and-rails-asset-pipeline/ seems to suggest that Rails simply doesn't check the public dir by default, and we have to manually specify the path?

Comment: Are you in production or development? Rails will serve static assets placed inside /public, but by default this is turned off in production for performance reasons.

Comment: I have `config.serve_static_assets = true`, that should allow it to serve files in /public right?